# Roots of a function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, roots

Why does the function: $f(y)=5y+4+8\cdot2^{3y} $ have only one root? What is the example of a similar function that has more than one root?

Comment: Please give some context to indicate that you digested the problem before passing an assignment along to Math.SE Readers.  You are in the best position to articulate the course materials this exercise was designed to reinforce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$f(y)=5y+4+8\cdot2^{3y}$$

is **surjective** since it is continuos and

$$\lim_{x\to \pm \infty} f(y)=\pm \infty$$

and **injective** since it is strictly increasing and thus more in general

$$f(y)=k$$

has an **unique solution** $\forall k\in \mathbb{R}$.

As an example of a similar function with more than one root let consider

$$h(y)=-100y+4+8\cdot2^{3y}$$

$$g(y)=5\sin{y}+4+8\cdot2^{3y}$$

Comment: What impact on function roots have surjectivity or injectivity?

Comment: It is a key fact, if $f(y)$ is surjective there exist at least one solution for $f(y)=k$, if $f(y)$ is injective we have no more than one solution, if $f(y)$ is both surjective and injective we have exactly one solution for all k.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this function ( $f(y)=5y+4+8\cdot2^{3y}$ ) is an ever increasing function. It doesn't go down for any interval .

For a function $f(x)$ to have more than one root, it must pass through x-axis once (**a root**) then go up (or down) then goes down (or up) and cut x-axis again (**another root**) and so on.

For a function which always increases (or decreases) can only cross x-axis once, not more than that. So, it can have only one root.

Comment: From the fact that f(y) is strictly increasing we can conclude taht it has at most one root. You need to observe also that it reach some negative value to be sure that $f(y)=0$ has solution or as an alternative note that $f(y)$, continuous, is also surjective and thus $f(y)=k$ has olution for all $k$.

Answer (score 2):

Nit-picking: this function has a single **zero**- only equations have "roots".  The zeros of the function f(x) are the roots of the **equation** f(x)= 0.

Now,

1) f is the sum of continuous functions so it is continuous.

2) f(1)= 5+ 4+ 8(8)= 73> 0 and f(-2)= -10+ 4+ 1= -5< 0.
  Therefore there exist at least one x such that f(x)= 0.

3) $f'(x)= 5+ 24 ln(2)2^{3x}$ is positive for all x.  Therefore f is an **increasing**.  There is only one value of x such that f(x)= 0.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this equation with the help of the LambertW function it is $$x=-1/15\,{\frac {12\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) +5\,{\it LambertW} \left( 3/5
\,\ln  \left( 2 \right) {2}^{3/5} \right) }{\ln  \left( 2 \right) }}=-1$$

Answer (score 0):

Your function $f$ is the sum of strictly increasing functions and therefore it must be strictly increasing. So, it can't be $0$ twice.

But $f(-1)=0$, and therefore it has one root.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more than one root, then assuming that the exponential term is positive, the coefficient of $y$ (which is $5$ in your function) must be negative. This will also mean that it's possible to have no roots, so you will have to have a constant term ($8$ in your function) can't be too large.

$g(y) = -5y-8+8\cdot 8^y$ is one such function.

Answer (score 0):

Let me use $x$ for the independent variable.

$y=f(x)=5x+4+8\cdot2^{3x}=5x+4+8^{x+1} = 5(x+1) + 8^{x+1} -1 $ has a monotonic behaviour going through zero at $x=-1,$  it is ever (strictly) increasing. So if at all, it can have a single crossing on x-axis with only a single root.